# Cannot find Google SendEmail function

Tags: google-apps-script, sendmail

I use the following code to send reminder emails to all the emails that are in a certain cell in column 7. But, it gives an error that "Cannot find SendEmail function". Would anyone please help me?

```js
function myfunction() {
var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
   // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow1 = sheet.getLastRow();
 
  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
  // is the headers, so start with row 5
  var startRow1 = 5;
 
  // grab column 6 (the 'days left' column) 
  var range = sheet.getRange(5,6,lastRow1-startRow1+1,1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var days_left_values = range.getValues();
   
  // Now, grab the reminder name column
  range = sheet.getRange(5, 3, lastRow1-startRow1+1, 1);
  var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();
  
  range = sheet.getRange(5, 7, lastRow1-startRow1+1, 1);
    var emails_info_values = range.getValues();
   
  var warning_count = 0;
  var msg = "";
   
  // Loop over the days left values
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
    if(days_left == 1) {
      // if it's exactly 1, do something with the data.
      var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
       
      msg = msg + "Reminder: "+reminder_name+" is due in "+days_left+" days.\n";
      warning_count++;
    }
    var emails= emails_info_values [i][0];
      if(warning_count) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("emails", "msg");
  }
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough parameters on the sendEmail method

Comment: This looks wrong `if(days_left =1= 0) {`

Comment: Are you sure these are strings. `MailApp.sendEmail("emails", "msg");` I think they should be variables.

Comment: @Cooper that was a typo. I corrected it. Thanks. I am not sure how to write the SendEmail function.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

Answer (score 0):

As Cooper mentioned in his comment The `MailApp.sendEmail()` function has inputs of either a mail object or if you wanted to send a simple string text as: `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)` where `recipient` is a string, `subject` is a string, and `body` is a string.

The error that your function returns is stating exactly:

```
Cannot find method sendEmail(string,string).
```

Which is meaning to say that it can't find the sendEmail function that handles two string inputs, when it's actually looking for `sendEmail(string,string,string)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried this code and I got this error: no recipients: emails (line 72, file "Code") . Although I got an error but it sent reminder and it works.

Comment: If you're wanting to use it to send reminders to yourself the that portion of the code would be: `sendEmail("youremailhere","subject","body")`  Replace the items int the quotes with your information and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

### Question

> Why my sendEmail is not working?

### Answer

Your sendEmail syntax is wrong, you are missing **subject**

---

1. Check the **correct syntax** for [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)

```js
function sendEmail(){
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
}
```

Example:

```js
function sendEmail(){
  MailApp.sendEmail("user4172070@gmail.com", "testing sendEmail via Apps Script", "It's working")
}
```

2. **Adapting** to your code

```js
MailApp.sendEmail(emails, "Email Subject", msg);
```

### Final version

```js
function myfunction() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow1 = sheet.getLastRow();

  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
  // is the headers, so start with row 5
  var startRow1 = 5;

  // grab column 6 (the 'days left' column) 
  var range = sheet.getRange(5, 6, lastRow1 - startRow1 + 1, 1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var days_left_values = range.getValues();

  // Now, grab the reminder name column
  range = sheet.getRange(5, 3, lastRow1 - startRow1 + 1, 1);
  var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

  range = sheet.getRange(5, 7, lastRow1 - startRow1 + 1, 1);
  var emails_info_values = range.getValues();

  var warning_count = 0;
  var msg = "";

  // Loop over the days left values
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];

    if(days_left == 1) {

      // if it's exactly 1, do something with the data.
      var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

      msg = msg + "Reminder: " + reminder_name + " is due in " + days_left + " days.\n";
      warning_count++;

    }

    var emails = emails_info_values [i][0];

    if(warning_count) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emails, "Email Subject", msg);
    }

  }

}
```

### Reference:

- [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)